# Nesting kernel functions for opencl

Tags: c++, c, opencl, mql5

I have a fairly complex mql5 for-loop code set that I need to run via opencl. What this will mean is I need to be able to have some kernel functions calling others. I have therefore experimented with this simple code and it fails to create a program (error 5105) when I call another function through it. Why?

```
               const string _cl_source=
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "__kernel void Tester()                                \r\n"
                "{                                                     \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "  float _margin = 10f;                                 \r\n"
                "  float _balance = 10f;                                \r\n"
                "  float _equity = 10f;                                 \r\n"
                "  float _openprice = 10f;                              \r\n"
                "  float _closeprice = 10f;                             \r\n"
                "  float _position = 10f;                               \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
/*fails on adding this line*/"  CouponReset(_margin,_balance,_equity,_openprice,_closeprice,_position);\r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "}                                                     \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "__kernel void CouponReset(float margin,                     \r\n"
                "                   float balance,                      \r\n"
                "                   float equity,                      \r\n"
                "                   float openprice,                      \r\n"
                "                   float closeprice,                     \r\n"
                "                   float position)               \r\n"
                "{                                                     \r\n"
                "  position = 0f;                         \r\n"
                "  openprice = 0f;                         \r\n"
                "  closeprice = 0f;                         \r\n"
                "  balance  = equity;                         \r\n"
                "  margin  = balance;                         \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n"
                "}                                                     \r\n"
                "                                                      \r\n";
```

Comment: Can you put .0f at the end of all zeroes?

Comment: Okay sure let me try. thx

Comment: Did that and still got the same error!

Comment: @huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik are you able to make this work with nested calls?

Comment: No, I dont have opencl 2.0 compatible hardware but there must be number of threads for the call.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I am using openCL 1.2

Comment: You cannot call another kernel from a kernel in 1.2. Only auxilliary functions allowed and they cannot be recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:Actually, I reviewed it, and it is possible to call a kernel from another kernel. However you should not do it, since it may lead you to problems down the road (specially if you use `__local` memory).

The key problem in your app is just the `0.0f` floats.

You can also do a separate function that is called by both kernels. And one of them is just a wrapper to the function.

```
void _CouponReset(float margin,                     
                   float balance,                      
                   float equity,                      
                   float openprice,                      
                   float closeprice,                     
                   float position)               
{                                                     
  position = 0.0f;                         
  openprice = 0.0f;                         
  closeprice = 0.0f;                         
  balance  = equity;                         
  margin  = balance;                                         
} 


__kernel void Tester()                                
{                                                     

  float _margin = 10.0f;                                 
  float _balance = 10.0f;                                
  float _equity = 10.0f;                                 
  float _openprice = 10.0f;                              
  float _closeprice = 10.0f;                             
  float _position = 10.0f;                               

  _CouponReset(_margin,_balance,_equity,_openprice,_closeprice,_position);

}     


__kernel void CouponReset(float margin,                     
                   float balance,                      
                   float equity,                      
                   float openprice,                      
                   float closeprice,                     
                   float position)               
{                                                     
  _CouponReset(margin, balance, equity, openprice, closeprice, position);                                         
}
```

Comment: Large part of why this works is because you included '.0f' at the end of the float data. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the reason this works simply that DarkZeros has reordered the function declarations so that the callee appears before the caller? Although I may be confusing myself about whether a kernel export can be called from device code.

Comment: @Lee yes that is true but while maintaining that order I realised I only needed two functions one void the other __kernel

Comment: @Lee I am failing to declare a string datatype. Is this possible in openCL 1.2?